# Can I initialize same variable name with different objects based on certain condition in java?

Tags: java, android, object

I have n number of objects and I need any one of them while execution based on certain condition. For Example.

```
switch(condition)
{
   case 1:
       Object1 obj = new Object1();
   break;
   case 2:
       Object2 obj = new Object2();
   break;
   default:
       defaultObject obj = new defaultObject();
   break;
}
int getItem = obj.getItemFromObject();
```

I am using the obj object in many other places in my code.
I know the question may seem trivial or even stupid but please help me. Or guide me towards an alternative approach.

Comment: You should follow this [link](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html) to **know** about scopes in `java`.

Comment: You have said several time what you don't want to do, but you haven't said what you do want to do.  Why `Object`.  Why can't you use a superclass or an interface?  `Or guide me towards an alternative approach` - people have done that but you've rejected the alternatives.  **What** are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use a super class to declare a subclass variable. Eg. If you want an object of either class P, Q or R, then use a super class A.

`P, Q, R will all extend A`.

Here is some (untested) code:

```
A obj = null;
switch(condition)
{
   case 1:
       obj = new P();
       break;
   case 2:
       obj = new Q();
       break;
   default:
       obj = new R();
       break;
}
```

Comment: You cannot do this as it will ask objects to be typecasted on each declaration

Comment: You can declare a subclass variable using a superclass.

Comment: See that is what I don't want to do. i do not want to declare a parent class for all my classes, but just call them individually when required.

Comment: Sorry, what you don't want to do is something you have to do.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, **does this even compile**? (I don't think it will compile at all)

You have declared your `obj` object inside `switch`, so it will complain `duplicate local variable obj` as you are having object with same variable name inside a single block.

Also it will not be able to find it when you invoke this (as it is outside its scope):

`int getItem = obj.getItemFromObject();` it will complain `obj cannot be resolved`

Unless you have declared and initialzed `obj` somewhere before.

And of course, you can do initialize your object based on conditions you want, that's not a big deal.

Comment: Yes it does not compile that is why I asked for and alternative approach. obj.getItemFromObject gives error as 'The method getItemFromObject(int) is undefined in type Object'

Answer (score 1):

Score of variable declared inside switch's case statement  corresponds to switch block. Hence, you can't re-declare same variable in different cases. However, you can assign same variable different values, depending upon case.

```
Object obj = null;
switch(condition)
{
   case 1:
       obj = new Object1();
   break;
   case 2:
       obj = new Object2();
   break;
   default:
       obj = new defaultObject();
   break;
}
int getItem = obj != null ? obj.getItemFromObject() : -1;
```

Comment: getItemFromObject not defined for type Object is the compilation error

Comment: Object is parent of all classes, so you should have no issues doing the assignment. However, to call getItemFromObject(), you need to typecast to Child Object. You should use instanceOf operator before doing that. Without knowing hierarchy of your classes, I can't narrow down the solution to your class structure. But general rule is Parent reference can hold child object

Comment: Bettwe design would be to have all child class extend or implement a common interface and define getItemFromObject() in that interface. Then you can invoke it via parent reference.

Comment: See that is what I don't want to do. i do not want to declare a parent class for all my classes, but just call them individually when required.